# Aligning cube faces Unity

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I am using a shader that uses a gradient noise node and time to add a wavy effect to a grid like texture. The issue with doing this is that it causes the lines to be misaligned on the different faces of the cubes.

[image]

What I would like is for the lines to be conjoined, like this (wavy effect not applied)

[image]

The shader graph layout I am using to generate this effect is

[image]

How can I go about fixing this issue so that all the lines are conjoined, but also have a wavy effect over time?

---

**Edit**

A rough sketch of what I am after. Here the black dots represent the physical shape of the object and the lines should be able to wave around the whole object and all be connected, regardless of whether there is an edge there or not.

[image]

Comment: Can you sketch for us what you want the cube to look like mid-wave? What *should* happen to the lines along the edges of the cube? Is it acceptable that they move off the edge and cause a kink in the lines crossing them? Or that they get doubled / hidden?

Comment: @DMGregory Apologies for the delayed response. I have edited the question with a rough sketch of what I am after. Ideally, the lines should be able to flow over the edge but I am not sure what is / isn't possible